# Regular expression negative lookbehind for multiple values

Tags: regex

I want to search my logs for exceptions. Starting Regex:

```
\wException\b
```

(The `\w` is so that I'm catching names of exceptions e.g. InvalidOperationException, and not just the word "exception", and the `\b` is to exclude other forms of exception e.g. "SomeExceptionHandler".)

This worked well, but I found one exception recurring very frequently that I'm not interested in; let's call it `FooException`. I changed my regex to include a negative lookbehind:

```
\w(?<!Foo)Exception\b
```

Great, now "FooException" has been excluded. Now I find that `BarException` is also creating a lot of noise and I want to exclude that too. So I figured I'd try a pipe inside the lookbehind:

```
\w(?<!(Foo|Bar))Exception\b
```

...but that was rejected as an invalid regex.

So, how can I exclude multiple strings in the lookbehind?

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't mention which tool you are using, but it is most likely rejecting your pattern because variable length lookbehinds are not supported by most regex flavors.
A simple workaround is to have multiple look-behinds:

```
\w(?<!Foo)(?<!Bar)Exception\b
```

You can also match the full exception:

```
\b(?!Foo|Bar)\w+Exception\b
```

Answer (score -2):

Starting with what did work for just Foo: `\w(?<!Foo)Exception\b`

To add another string, try `\w+(?<!(?:Foo|Bar))Exception\b`

... replacing `Foo` with `(?:Foo|Bar)`.

Explanation:

A thing inside the parens.

`?:` meaning don't capture.

`|` for `or` in this list of strings.

*Also added `+` for the whole preceding word.*

Comment: Er, what? That's exactly  what they say they did, but couldn't get to work.